# How to draw a vector graphic on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

If I want to draw a normal bitmap image on a JPanel I simply call "graphics.drawImage(...)" in the panels "paint(Graphics graphics)" or "paintComponent(Graphics graphics)" method. How can I draw a vector graphic on a JPanel?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batik is an SVG library for Java.  You should be able to use a JSVGCanvas to do what you want.

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/swing.html